# Create key value pair object from $.each loop

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create an object with key value pairs in a loop through some DOM elements.

Some background on the overall context of what I'm doing: this section of code is part of a questionnaire I'm creating.

This is the code in question:

```
var resultsView = {};        
function sumAnswers(className) {
       //some stuff here

        $(className:checked).each(function() {
        //some other code here to sum answers  

        var text = $(this).siblings('.question').text();
        var answer = $(this).next('label').text();
        resultsView[text] = answer;
        });
  }
```

I'm trying to add the question text and selected answer text in a key/value relationship to an object, that way I can later pass it through AJAX to a PHP file.

The problem is that when I console.log resultsView, it only adds one question/answer multiple times. Changing the operator to += isn't working either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the input? What is the output? The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to answer and the more helpful the answers will be. Please consider to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo as well.

Comment: Could you create fiddle or the demo? Since I am not quite understand the 'adds one question/answer multiple times'.

Comment: You probably want to call the push method. resultsView.push( { "text":"foo", "answer":"bar" } );

Comment: i managed to recreate your issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/kFzmZ/  if you look at the "resultsView" object outside of the loop, you get the expected variable assignment. don't repeat console.log in the loop.

Comment: chrisvillanueva, like you said, I had console.log in the loop and the strange output was throwing me off. Is there a technical reason to not have the console in the loop? That's helped me debug things at times (obviously this time it backfired), but if its bad practice, I'll shape up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to see such a issue could you please check it in the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sZYaf/19/

I have create similar code in the above specified case

```
$("#check").click(function(){

var resultsView = {};
$(".check:checked").each(function() {
    //some other code here to sum answers  

    var text = $(this).siblings('.question').text();
    var answer = $(this).next('label').text();
    resultsView[text] = answer;

    });
 alert(resultsView["question1"]  + resultsView["question2"] );
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You're absolutely right Sridhar...there is no problem. I'm embarrassed. The output to the console was simply in a different format than what I was expecting and it seemed broken. Thanks for being willing to help.